# Do higher levels have a larger view distance

Tags: ingress

It seems to me that I can see farther after gaining another level, but I always forget to compare.

Will the scanner display larger distances as you level up?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No. I have not seen any sensible difference of maximum viewing distance when comparing screen between a very low level and a lvl 16. The format of the screen can have a low impact, but that's it.

Comment: I just recently leveled from 7 to 8 and confirmed that there was no difference.  Maybe what I was seeing before was an overall change with the scanner after an update.  Thanks for the quick response!